# Как сузить срабатывание вотчера набора реплик MongoDB по свойству документа в фильтре?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Доброго времени!**

Есть стандартная конструкция вотчера реплики MongoDB.
Понимаю как настроить фильтр на срабатывание по типу операции, но "лишних" срабатываний довольно много, что не есть хорошо, поэтому необходимо сузить срабатывание вотчера, настроив фильтр на свойство документа. Попробовал расширить свойствами $match, но что то это не помогло.

*Как правильно сузить срабатывание вотчера через $match?*
 **Что добавить в фильтр?**

```
const options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }

function watchUpdate ( id ) {

    try {

        // в фильтре сужаем выборку по типу операции и уникальному свойству
        let filter = [

            {
                $match: { 

                   'fullDocument._id': id, // добавленное свойство
                   $and: [ { operationType: 'update' } ] 
                }
            }
        ]

        let changeStream = collection.watch ( filter, options )

        changeStream.on ( 'change', data => {

            // тут получаем измененный документ
            console.log ( data )
        } )
    } catch ( err ) { res.send ( err ) }
}
```